# How to find processes which uses the most RAM in last X seconds?

Tags: linux, memory, bash-scripting, monitoring

Could you please help me to sort this out? I'm trying to write a bash script which will monitor ram usage (not only ram but cpu and network as well) and show me 3 processes which use the most ram in past X seconds? I know that I can find which processes use the most ram by running the following:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $2, $4, $11}' | sort -k2rn | head -n 3
```

But how can this be repeated? I want to see not the situation at this exactly second, but monitor the situation for (let it be) 60 seconds and see top 3 processes which was using the most ram.

Comment: Why don't you just use top in batch mode (-b) specifying -d and -n according to your needs?